# App not working properly on lower API level but still above minimum

Tags: java, android, api, version

I've been developing an **Android App** which is targeting **API LEVEL 23** and its **minimum API LEVEL is 16** . Most of the time I've tested the app on my phone which is running **Android 6.0 (API level 23)**. But I tried it on a friend's phone which is running **Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)** (I made sure I didn't use anything above that API level). So I thought because it is above the minimum my app requires that everything should've worked properly. However some colors have changed (buttons colors, background color, fonts colors), back button on child activities don't appear, there is a *Onclicklistener* that doesn't work either.

Is my only solution to recode everything that now is not working properly?

Will changing the compile version do anything?

What other solutions do I have?

Answer (score 1):

**How did you export the apk?** 
If you take the .apk from /bin folder there will be problems with all devices except with one with you where releasing

**Witch theme are you using for that colors?**
If you use default themes, obviously there will be different colors and forms of every different version (and phone model)

**Will changing the compile version do anything?**
No

Best reguards :)

Comment: I export the apk from the app folder. Im using a theme I made myself which I set as default, but not the one set as default when app is created. Anything wrong with that? What else can I do? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you took the .apk file from /bin folder (inside the project) **that's wrong!!!**
You have to export and compile importing and cleaning all libs and stuff from that project. Eclipse and Android Studio has a tool for make it automatically

**If you are using eclipse**
1.-Click right to the project
2.-export
3.-Android (Export Android Application)
4.-select project, create a new keystore (I think u havent one created yet) [if you are going to upload the .apk into play store, dont lose this keystore]
5.-Set your alias, password, validity and name

**If you are using Android Studio**
Google it :p

Comment: I think that is what Im doing, in **Android Studio** its called *Generated Signed APK*. Just to give you more information it is working properly on different devices, not only mine. I still think it has to be something related to the **API LEVELS** because on phones running level 17 it has multiple problems, but phones running 22 or 23 it is working fine. What are your thoughts? I might be completly wrong. Thanks